# Jquery Delay overrule on next link or div hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a code where a div appears if someone hovers other div, I added the 5 seconds delay so the shown div stays but the problem is that I want it to stay until next link hovered. Means I need the first div to be disappeared if the second link hovered.

Here's JS Fiddle link of my existing code:
http://jsfiddle.net/np87e/880/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#theLink3").hover(
    function () {
        $("#theDiv3").slideDown();
    },
    function () {
        $("#theDiv3").delay(5000).slideUp();
    }
);
$("#theLink4").hover(
    function () {
        $("#theDiv4").slideDown();
    },
    function () {
        $("#theDiv4").delay(5000).slideUp();
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call slideUp() of the div in next elements mouseenter callback

```
$("#theLink3").hover(function () {
    $("#theDiv4").stop(true, true).slideUp();
    $("#theDiv3").slideDown();
}, function () {
    $("#theDiv3").delay(5000).slideUp();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7ps0wh85/)

Note: I'm not a fan of writing individual hover handlers like you have done. So

```
<a href="" id="theLink3" class="trigger">hover here</a>
<div id="theDiv3" class="target">this is the div</div>
<hr />

<a href="" id="theLink4" class="trigger">hover here</a>
<div id="theDiv4" class="target">this is the div</div>
<hr />
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $targets = $('.target');
    $(".trigger").hover(function () {
        var $target = $(this).next('.target').stop(true, true).slideDown();
        $targets.not($target).stop(true, true).slideUp();
    }, function () {
        $(this).next('.target').stop(true, true).delay(5000).slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7ps0wh85/2/)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes... :(

Comment: Basically I know nothing about Jquery or Javascript. I am just fan of these languages so I watch tutorials and problems and end up writing my needed one codes. I don't know if I am writing lengthy or buggy codes.. lol.. Your first code works for me though.. I am trying to learn all this...